# Restarting Asynctask in fragment after using replace transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, fragment

I am using `AsyncTask` in my fragment for loading a list of data by Json. After clicking each list items this list fragment is replaced by details fragment containing details information. Then in new fragment (details fragment) user presses back button. Then again list fragment starts.
The problem is that Asynctask reloads again to fetch list items. I don't want this. I want to show previously loaded list. Here is the code:

```
    public class MainList extends Fragment {
public MainList(){}

ArrayList<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
Country country;
Button btnLoadMore;
ListView listView;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
public static String received_id;
// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
int current_page = 0;
int last_item;
int total_items = 32;
boolean continue_loading = true;
boolean loadingMore = false;
View footerView;
public ImageLoader_Json imageLoader;
int currentPosition = 0;
MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;

private static String url_all_products_LoadMore = "http://www.hitel.ir/FarsiPlanet/Apps.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_RATE = "rate";
private static final String TAG_RATINGCOUNT = "ratingcount";
private static final String TAG_SHORT_DESCRIPTION = "short_description";



// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;
String Category;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items_list, container, false);

    Category = getArguments().getString("category");

    footerView= ((LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.loading_footer, null,false);
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView.addFooterView(footerView);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader_Json(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    displayListView();

    return rootView;
}

private void displayListView() {
    //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
    dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.country_info, countryList);



    listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;

            if((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore)){     

                new loadMoreListView().execute();
            } 
        }
    });

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            final String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText().toString();
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putString(TAG_PID, pid);
            data.putString("TAG_Category", Category);
            Fragment fragment = new Details_Restaurant();
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            fragment.setArguments(data);
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).addToBackStack("f_02").commit();
        }
    });

    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    listView.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition, 0); 
}

private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Country> {

    private ArrayList<Country> countryList;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, 
            ArrayList<Country> countryList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, countryList);
        this.countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
        this.countryList.addAll(countryList);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView code;
        TextView name;
        RatingBar rate;
        TextView ratingcount;
        TextView short_description;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));
        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.country_info, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.ratingcount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingCount);
            holder.short_description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.short_description);
            holder.rate = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
            holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pid);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final Country country = countryList.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(country.getName());
        holder.ratingcount.setText(country.getRatingCount());
        holder.short_description.setText(country.getShort_description());
        holder.rate.setRating(country.getRate());
        holder.code.setText(country.getCode());

        return convertView;
    }
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

class loadMoreListView extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        /*
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("درحال دريافت اطلاعات...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show(); */
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        String firts_item = Integer.toString(current_page*10);
        int success;
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", firts_item));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", Category));

            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            // Note that product details url will use GET request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    url_all_products_LoadMore, "GET", params);

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    Float rate = (float) c.getInt(TAG_RATE);
                    String ratingcount = c.getString(TAG_RATINGCOUNT);
                    String short_description = c.getString(TAG_SHORT_DESCRIPTION);

                    country = new Country(id,name,rate,ratingcount,short_description,"","");
                    countryList.add(country);
                }
            }
            else{
                continue_loading = false;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        current_page += 1;
        if (continue_loading) {
            currentPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            displayListView();
            loadingMore = false;

        } else {
            listView.removeFooterView(footerView);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to include @Override before calling onScrollStateChanged and onScroll

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;

        if((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore)){     

            new loadMoreListView().execute();
        } 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when you perform the replace() action on the fragment, you are removing the list fragment , thus when tapping back, you are replacing the details fragment with your listfragment which invokes onCreateView() as part of the fragments lifecycle.

I would try to either keep a static booelan set to true when the asynctask's onPostExecute() ends, so the next time the list fragment's onCreateView() will be invoked , you would check the value of the flag and if set to true will not execute the task, but just set the adapter with the old static data.

Comment: What do you mean by 'old static data?' You mean I save everything before `onPostExecute`?

Comment: yes, you can save it in cache, or in sqlite, whatever fits.